# MVC razor html a href attribute is ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Following code is executed fine

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                        <div class="sub-category-item">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">
                                    @item.Name
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

this works also

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                        <div class="sub-category-item">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <text>@item.SeName</text>                                    
                                @*<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">
                                    @item.Name
                                </a>*@
                            </h2>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

But when I want to write same code with simple a href attribute as below, VS ignores the line. I cant even set a break point over the line a href. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                        <div class="sub-category-item">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a href="@item.SeName" title="@item.PictureModel.Title" />
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

Comment: are you experiencing an actual error? tbh i don't think any code is being executed here, you're just inserting a value.

Comment: no, compile error, no run time error but just simply line is ignored. what do you mean by any code is being executed? where do you see the problem with others?

Comment: @user1666620 i can set a breakpoint on foreach line and it jumps to there and foreach is executed but never goes inside it where the a href line is. no error is popped out.

Comment: when the application is launched, is the href appearing correctly in the browser? your comment says something about a compile error, are you suffering one?

Comment: did you checked error in develop tools of browser?

Comment: You can't set a breakpoint as there's no executing code (possibly, maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add link text:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
 {
     <div class="item-box">
         <div class="sub-category-item">
             <h2 class="title">
                 <a href="@item.SeName" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">@item.PictureModel.Title</a>
             </h2>
         </div>
     </div>
 }
```

Comment: opps, it was that much simple. thanks. It is strange that VS doesnt give any error or warning but just ignores the line when no link text is given. thanks.

Comment: @batmaci formal - it's not an error, maybe you want to add text later with javascript - compiler does not know

Comment: @batmaci you can check it as answer :)

Comment: Technically speaking, a self-closing anchor *is* an error, given that it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @TiesonT. never thought about it, but you are right